# Custom UITableViewCell layer cutoff

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView with custom cells. In the `awakeFromNib` of the cell custom class I add the cell labels etc. using AutoLayout. They display fine when viewed first time. 
(Blue rectangle is a single `UITableViewCell`)

[image]

The problem is that after I swipe the table view so that some cells goes offscreen then back again (i.e. cells are re-layout) the cell layer gets cutoff.

[image]

Comment: How are you programmatically adding your subviews? Are you calling ```[self addSubview:myView]``` or ```[self.contentView addSubview:myView];```?

Comment: @HectorMatos I tried both methods, same result

Comment: Another way to debug is to go to Xcode, Click Debug>View Debugging>Capture View Hierarchy on Xcode 6+. Is there possibly a view being added to the bottom left corner of your view? Try to pull it out of awakeFromNib. You shouldn't have to add your subviews programmatically if they are already being added to your storyboard. You can set up your auto layout in the storyboard as well. My guess is that awakeFromNib is being called when the cells are being reused which causes your subviews to be added multiple times.

Comment: @HectorMatos Thanks a lot Hector, I didn't know of this debugging technique. It helped me locate where the problem is. There was an unused UIView that was placed above the labels and that's why It was cutoff. Thanks again.

Comment: Anytime! Would you like me to put my comments into an answer for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to debug is to go to Xcode, Click `Debug>View Debugging>Capture` View Hierarchy on Xcode 6+. It looks like there is possibly an unused view being added to the bottom left corner of your view? Try the view debugging to see if that's the case.